# Comments destroyed the equation's shape

Tags: equations, comments

I need to make some comments for every part of the equation. The result (the upper part of the figure) shown that the structure/shape/position of the equation is destroyed by the comments. Can some one plz help me to get something which is similar to the down part of the figure by some examples or updating/fixing my code.

Cheers
S.l.

[image]

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
3.0 = x + y\\
1.5 = 2x - y\\
0.2 = x - y
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace {
\begin{bmatrix}
3.0 \\
1.5 \\
0.2 
\end{bmatrix}
}_\text{Obs. Vector $\mathop L\limits_{n,1}$}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
2 & -1\\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
}_\text{\minibox{Matrix with coefficients of linear function model \\ Coefficient matrix or design matrix $\mathop A\limits_{n, \nu}$}}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\Y
\end{bmatrix}
}_\text{vector of unknown $\mathop X\limits_{\nu ,1}$}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: please edit your example to be a complete document so that people can reproduce the problem and test their answers.

Comment: A general principle you can bear in mind in these situations: use `\smash{comment}` to make LaTeX allocate no space at all for `comment`. That means it won't shove other things out of the way by making room for itself.

Comment: @JohnWickerson -- not quite.  `\smash` wipes out the vertical dimension of what it operates on, but to wipe out the horizontal dimension, something like `\clap` and friends (or `\mathclap`) is needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton D'oh, I knew I shouldn't have just guessed from memory! `:)`

Comment: @JohnWickerson -- but the principle is good, you just have to remember that *all* dimensions have to be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A job for stacks, with the key being the setting of the parameter `\def\useanchorwidth{T}`, which says that any over/under-stacked material is to be assumed of zero width, and only the "anchor" of the stack accounts for the overall stack width.

I also opted to center justify the center-matrix's underset.  It can be made left-aligned by changing the `\Longstack{...}` to `\def\useanchorwidth{F}\Longstack[l]{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
3.0 = x + y\\
1.5 = 2x - y\\
0.2 = x - y
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stackalignment{r}
\stackunder{
  \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
      3.0 \\
      1.5 \\
      0.2 
    \end{bmatrix}
  }
}{
  \scriptstyle\text{Obs. Vector} \mathop L\limits_{n,1}
}
=
\def\stackalignment{c}
\stackunder[2ex]{
  \underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    2 & -1\\
    1 & -1
  \end{bmatrix}
  }_{\rule{.4pt}{7ex}}
}{
  \Longstack{
    \scriptstyle\text{Matrix with coefficients of linear function model} \\
    \scriptstyle\text{Coefficient matrix or design matrix} \mathop A\limits_{n, \nu}
  }
}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackunder{
  \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
      x\\Y
    \end{bmatrix}
  }
}{
  \scriptstyle\text{vector of unknown} \mathop X\limits_{\nu ,1}
}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want the equal signs of the equation system aligned and centered, you could replace your `eqnarray*` with

```
\usepackage{tabstackengine}% use in lieu of stackengine
```

...

```
\noindent\hfil\alignCenterstack{
3.0 =& x + y\\
1.5 =& 2x - y\\
0.2 =& x - y\\
}\hfil
```